# Compare a number that is entered by the user to a value (EBX)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to compare that the user has entered and saved in the stack to a constant number that I made. The constants are called `min` and `max`.

The number the user enters is saved in a variable called `Num`, which is in `ebp+8` in the stack. I want to use `cmp` to compare that value to the constants so I can check if the number is within the allowed range.

Picture of the problem is provided.[The problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKje1.jpg)

```
  TITLE template


    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

    min = 10
    max = 200
    lo = 100
    hi = 999

    .data

    ask         BYTE    "How many numbers should be generated? [10 .. 200]: ",0                         
    Num         DWORD   ?                                                                               
    wrong       BYTE    "Invalid input",0                                                               

    .code
    main PROC

        push    OFFSET Num
        call    getData


        exit
    main ENDP


    getData PROC

    ;Set up the stack frame
        push    

ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]
;Ask the user
again:
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]
    mov edx, OFFSET ask
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadDec
    mov [ebx], eax

;Check the input
    cmp [ebx], min
    jl  nono
    cmp [ebx], max
    jg  nono
    jmp okay
nono:
    mov edx, OFFSET wrong
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    loop    again
okay:
    pop     ebp
    ret     4
getData ENDP


END main
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post a picture of the problem. Especially one that does not show all relevant information (how is `min` defined). Anyway, my guess is you are comparing 2 memory operands and that is not valid. Load one into a register first. Incidentally, it's already in `eax` so just do `cmp eax, min`. Also, see an instruction set reference.

Comment: Please post your code as text, pictures are useless.

Comment: Probably the assembler doesn't know the operand size for the cmp immediate operations. Depending on your assembler, probably you need to use `cmpl` or `cmp dword ptr`. (Or maybe something else; I'm not sure which assembler this is.)

Comment: I am sorry about that. I am new to the website.
I just posted the code to question.

Comment: Anyone :(  . . .

Comment: As prl suggested use add `dword ptr` to the compares. The assembler can't deduce from the operands the size of the data at [ebx] to compare min and max against. So you need to specify on the memory operand the size. Try `cmp dword ptr [ebx], min` and `cmp dword ptr [ebx], max` . That forces the comaprison dor compare the 32-bit DWORD at the memory address pointed to by EBX againt the constant (immediate) values of `min` and `max`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments noted, you wrote something like `cmp [ebx],10` in the code, which is ambiguous for assembler (in 32b mode 3 different instructions can be assembled from that, targetting either BYTE, WORD or DWORD memory size with 3 [size-]different immediate values), so `cmp dword ptr [ebx],10` will resolve that, but there are more problems, here is fixed code + advices in `;*` comments (with asterisk):

```lisp
getData PROC
;Set up the stack frame
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
;Ask the user
again:
    mov edx, OFFSET ask
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadDec
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]     ;* ebx loaded more locally to its usage
      ;* it's anti-performance, but makes source easier to read+check
      ;* and you don't need to worry about some subroutine to modify ebx
      ;* as it was waiting for user input, so there's no problem with performance
    mov [ebx], eax

;Check the input
    ;* cmp dword ptr [ebx], min
    ;*     ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ this would work, but the value is still in eax
    cmp eax, min    ;* so why not to compare that!
    jl  nono
    cmp eax, max    ;* also here
    jg  nono
;* okay, just return
    pop     ebp
    ret     4

nono:
    mov edx, OFFSET wrong
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    jmp     again    ;* JMP, not LOOP!
      ;* Loop will modify ECX and when ECX decreases to zero, loop will not jump
getData ENDP
```

Actually you may do the check right after `ReadDec` and store the value only when it is within legal range, like this:

```lisp
    ...
    call    ReadDec
;Check the input
    cmp eax, min
    jl  nono
    cmp eax, max
    jg  nono
;* good value, store it + return
    mov edx, [ebp+8]   ;* and I would use EDX, already modified for WriteString
    mov [edx], eax     ;* so no need to modify also EBX
    pop     ebp
    ret     4
    ...  ; "nono:" code from above
```